# What are the geometric data structures that can support nearest neighbor queries in the 2d plane?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

I was wondering if there exist a data structure that can support the following operations(ideally in log(n)

time where n is the number of points):

1. Nearest neighbor queries where the nearest neighbor to a point is
   defined as the function that takes the point and returns the point
   that gives the minimum sum of its weight plus its distance from the
   queried point.
2. Insertion of a new point into the data structure
3. Bulk Updating of the weight of all current points in the structure by a
   given number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the weights are never negative, we can define a distance
function on **R**<sup>2</sup> × **R**<sup>+</sup> (points × weights) as
d((p, w), (p′, w′)) = d(p, p′) + |w − w′|. Weird metric, but it plugs
right into the cover tree nearest neighbors algorithm. Then we query a
point p by first embedding it as (p, v) where v = 0.

To add a constant c to all of the weights, we adjust the “vantage point”
v by v ← v − c. A new point p added to the structure with weight w
embeds as (p, w − v).

Comment: What are the time complexities of each of the operations that you describe, O(logn)?

Comment: @Alex yes, albeit with a large constant IIRC.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details in your description? I was looking at the cover tree nearest neighbors algorithm and it seems that the complexities of its operations have another parameter which is called the Expansion Constant